# CopyError - OFS.CopySupport.manage_pasteObjects limited to ~ <160 objects?

Tags: plone, zope

I'm using a view to archive old content by moving it into another folder.
(catalog search for enddate more than N months ago, pass id's into the following command:

```
target.manage_pasteObjects( source.manage_cutObjects(idsToArchive) )
```

One or two years ago moving about 800 or even more objects was no problem.
Today I need to limit the catalog search to around 80 items, otherwise I get
a

```
    Module OFS.CopySupport, line 193, in manage_pasteObjects
CopyError: 

The data in the clipboard could not be read, possibly due to cookie data being truncated by your web browser. Try copying fewer objects.
```

running plone 4.1.6 / Zope2-2.13.15.

I already tried to deactivate beaker-session-datamanager (still the same problems)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You installed the latest Plone hotfix, [20130618](http://plone.org/products/plone-hotfix/releases/20130618). It includes a DDOS-prevention measure limiting the size of the `__cp` cookie data to 8kb (decompressed).

Future Zope versions will also include this fix.

To work around this temporarily your only option is to increase the maximum size default. Doing this *will* allow other threads use larger cookies as well until you restore the default:

```python
from OFS.CopySupport import _cb_decode

_default_maxsize = _cb_decode.func_defaults[0]

def _increase_maxsize(newsize):
    # Patch the maxsize default
    _cb_decode.func_defaults = (newsize,)

def _restore_maxsize(newsize):
    # Patch the maxsize default
    _cb_decode.func_defaults = (_default_maxsize,)
```

The cookie data consists almost entirely of object paths (absolute paths as tuples) as `marshall` dumps, you'll have to estimate a suitable maximum size from that.

Comment: thanks for the detailed response martijn. i estimated the average size of each brain by using the source folder's path and a length of 50 characters for ids:

avgSize = sys.getsizeof(marshal.dumps(list(source.getPhysicalPath())+['x'*50]))

multiply the avgSize by the nr ids we are going to pass to manage_cutObject et voila!

Comment: @fRiSi: Much better work-around; do note that `sys.getsizeof()` is not the best tool to use here; just use `len()` on the `marshall` output instead.